# In a search of perfect batch script for editing the hosts file

Tags: performance, algorithm, windows, batch

I want to edit Windows **hosts** file in the best way for the end user, using a batch-only solution. I ended up with this script, which works fine, but since I don't have enough knowledge, the syntax is very poor. So please, may you take a look and tell me how to improve it, especially the `=999` part (for some reason I can't use there `=replaced`, and can't use `=0` as it breaks future iterations):

```
REM In short:
REM   FOR for every line of the hosts file
REM     FOR to check current line if it contains our hosts and replace if so
REM   FOR for our hosts if they not been replaced and thus shall be inserted at the end of the hosts file

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set hostspath=%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

set hosts[0]=first.host.com
set hosts[1]=second.host.com
set ip=127.1.2.3

set hostslenght=0
:hostsLenght
if defined hosts[%hostsLenght%] ( 
    set /a "hostslenght+=1"
    GOTO :hostslenght
)

>"%hostspath%.new" (
    set /a hostslenght-=1
    for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%a in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /n /r /c:".*" "%hostspath%"') do (
        set skipline= 
        for /L %%h in (0,1,!hostslenght!) do (
            echo %%b|find "!hosts[%%h]!" >nul
            if not errorlevel 1 (
                echo %ip%       !hosts[%%h]!
                set /a hosts[%%h]=999
                set skipline=true
            )
        )
        if not "!skipline!"=="true" (echo.%%b)
    )

    for /L %%h in (0,1,!hostslenght!) do (
        if not !hosts[%%h]!==999 (
            echo %ip%       !hosts[%%h]!
        )
    )
)

REM move /y "%hostspath%" "%hostspath%.bak" >nul || echo Can't backup %hostspath%. Try run the script as Administrator.
REM move /y "%hostspath%.new" "%hostspath%" >nul || echo Can't update %hostspath%. Try run the script as Administrator.

endlocal
echo The hosts file is updated.
pause
```

It would be great to get rid of `set /a hostslenght-=1` (initially I wanted to decrement this in `for` loops, but it's wont decremented that way), and the last `for` as well.

**Upd:** Version 2. Horrible `=999` is defeated, but there is still problems with `hostslenght` (is there a way to not enumerate the hosts count?), and it will be nice to preserve original file's last line (`echo` is always leave empty line at the end, but I don't see a easy way to detect last `for` iteration)

Before:

```
...
set /a hosts[%%h]=999
...
if not !hosts[%%h]!==999 (
```

After:

```
...
set hosts[%%h]=
...
if defined hosts[%%h] (
```

Comment: Oof. Why batch? If you're specifically targeting Windows, PowerShell is more ergonomic.

Comment: @Reinderien Batch is simpler for end user, just download and run. And such solution is a classic in my specific case.

Comment: It looks like your goal is to map multiple hostnames to 127.0.0.1 as a kind of black hole, and you want to do this on multiple machines that you manage? How are you deploying and getting this script to run on your hosts? It seems like it would be far more practical to run your own DNS proxy server (such as dnsmasq or similar).

Comment: @200_success For the end user, it's just a way to use some application with my server without editing the application files. I already have a good script for those who expect nothing but a working application, but I also want to have the perfect script for those who will check its source before running it.